# c# How to escape a directory path with differend letters?

Tags: c#, string, path, escaping

Hi there I have this

```
string s = @"A:\"
```

And i have to change the letter, so i need this

```
string s= @" + Letter + :\"
```

I already tried something, but it was lame...

Comment: In addition to all the answers you got: when you create directory strings you should always consider to use `Path.Combine`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
string s = Letter + @":\";
```

If you're using C# 6.0, you could use interpolated strings. *(but you need to escape the `\`)*

```
string s = $"{Letter}:\\";
```

Comment: you can use     Regex.Unescape() to unescape, pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to escape the backslash, because it's a special character, by using two backslashes, like this:

```
string s = Letter + ":\\"
```

or you need to indicate that the string with the backslash should be interpreted "verbatim" by putting an `@` in front of it, like this:

```
string s = Letter + @":\"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string format to help.  There is also string interpolation if you are using c# 6.0.

```
var Letter = "A";
string s = string.Format(@"{0}:\", Letter);
```

String interpolation with c# 6.0

```
string s = $"{Letter}:\\";
```